# Response header difference between XMLHttpRequest and jQuery AJAX method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, ajax

**Dears my problem is not duplicate.**

code:

```
var data = {'userId': window.cookie.get('userId'),
    'sessionId': window.cookie.get('sessionId')}

$.post(window.DbUrl + '/test', data, function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

I try to send ajax with jquery post and response is:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://localhost:8080
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1011
...
```

code:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('sessionId', window.cookie.get('sessionId'));
formdata.append('userId', window.cookie.get('userId'));
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", selff.myProgressHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("load", myCompleteHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("error", myErrorHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("abort", myAbortHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", window.DbUrl + '/test',true);
ajax.send(formdata);
```

I try with XMLHttpRequest in same URL response is:

```
Allow:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:4
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

In the nodejs express server, missing  `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers.

But when ajax with XMLHttpRequest to php server every thing is Ok.

nodejs server:

```
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://localhost:8080');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization');
    res.end('welcome');
});
```

php server is ok:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:8080');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization');

?>wellcome
```

What is the problem? why php server is ok both nodojs is not, why jquery ok in any server?

Comment: `Content-Length: 4` is less than the length of `welcome`. What do you see in the response data?

Comment: And `Content-Length: 1011` is much longer than `wellcome`.

Comment: I suspect some error is occurring when you go to the node server, since it's not sending back any of the headers you set.

Comment: @Barmar  he he Realy ? I know this :( what is the reason?

Comment: @Barmar the length is sample not real

Comment: Check the difference in request headers. Also check your server log to see if any errors are shown there.

Comment: @Barmar has any error :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason but use the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package if you want to fix it.
Because the package has trigger on express request, send header before you send manual.

Comment: why use `cros` I use the headers?